# Why isn't my php inputting the data? Am I missing something?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

As stated in the above title, I am completely perplexed as to why my site doesn't insert the data into my database (and yes I've made all the necessary columns and stuff). It is probably related to the radio buttons and the "Preke" tag so if you see anything I've messed up on, it'd help me out a lot!

Hese is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<?php

// define variables and set to empty values
$VarErr = $PavErr = $AdErr = $PreErr = $PkErr = $KiekErr = "";
$Vardas = $Pavarde = $Adresas = $Preke = $Pk = $Kiekis =  "";

?>

<html class="no-js" lang="en">

<head>
 <title>Dailės parduotuvė</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
              <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stilius.css">
        </head>
<body class="content "> 


<div class="container">
                   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark ">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Kauno dailė</a>

                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>

                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="Visos.html">Visos prekės</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="Uzsakymas.php">Užsisakymas</a>
                                </li>                                        
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Kontaktai</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>


<div>                   

<div class="content sm-4 text-center">
<h2>Užsisakymo forma</h2>
<p><span class="error">* privalomi laukai</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  


  <p class="text-center">Vardas</p><br>
  <input type="text" name="Vardas" value="<?php echo $Vardas;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $VarErr;?></span>

   <p class="text-center">Pavarde</p><br>
  <input type="text" name="Pavarde" value="<?php echo $Pavarde;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $PavErr;?></span>

   <p class="text-center">Adresas</p><br>
  <input type="text" name="Adresas" value="<?php echo $Adresas;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $AdErr;?></span><br>

  Prekės rūšis:<br>
         <input type="radio" name="Preke" value="Vienišas(-a)" checked>Dažai(5&euro;)<br>
         <input type="radio" name="Preke" value="Susituokęs(-usi)">Teptukas(2&euro;)<br>
         <input type="radio" name="Preke" value="Išsiskyręs(-usi)">Pieštukas(2&euro;)<br>
         <input type="radio" name="Preke" value="Našlys(-ė)">Ofiso įrankis(1&euro;)<br>
          <span class="error">* <?php echo $PreErr;?></span>
         <br>



  <p class="text-center">Prekės kodas</p><br>
  <input type="number" name="Pk" value="<?php echo $Pk;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $PkErr;?></span>

  <p class="text-center">Kiekis</p><br>
  <input type="number" name="Kiekis" value="<?php echo $Kiekis;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $KiekErr;?></span>
  <br>


  <!-- Input For Add Values To Database-->
            <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Užsisakyti">



</div>
</div> 
<div class="content py-5">

<?php




if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["Vardas"])) {
    $VarErr = "Įveskite vardą";
  } else {
    $Vardas= test_input($_POST["Vardas"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$Vardas)) {
      $VarErr = "Galima vesti tik su raidėmis"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["Pavarde"])) {
    $PavErr = "Įveskite pavardę";
  } else {
    $Pavarde = test_input($_POST["Pavarde"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$Pavarde)) {
      $PavErr = "Galima vesti tik su raidėmis"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["Adresas"])) {
    $AdErr = "Įveskite adresą";
  } else {
    $Adresas= test_input($_POST["Adresas"]);
  }
}  
  if (empty($_POST["Preke"])) {
    $PreErr = "Pasirinkite prekės tipą";
  } else {
    $Preke = test_input($_POST["Preke"]);
 }  
  if (empty($_POST["Pk"])) {
    $Pk = "Įveskite prekės kodą";
  } else {
    $Pk = test_input($_POST["Pk"]);
}
  if (empty($_POST["Kiekis"])) {
    $KiekErr = "Įveskite kiekį";
  } else {
    $Kiekis = test_input($_POST["Kiekis"]);
}


function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}


$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password ="";
$database = "uzsakymas";

try{
    $connect = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database);
} 
catch(mysqli_sql_exception $ex){
    echo 'database connection error';
}
//insert
if(isset($_POST['insert'])) {

    $Vardas = $_POST['Vardas'];
    $Pavarde = $_POST['Pavarde'];
    $Adresas = $_POST['Adresas'];
    $Preke = $_POST['Preke'];
    $Pk = $_POST['Pk'];
    $Kiekis = $_POST['Kiekis'];



    $insert_query = "INSERT INTO uzsakymai (Vardas,Pavarde,Adresas,Preke,Pk,Kiekis,)VALUES('$Vardas','$Pavarde','$Adresas','$Preke','$Pk','$Kiekis')";
    try {
        $insert_result = mysqli_query($connect,$insert_query);

        if($insert_result){
            if(mysqli_affected_rows($connect) > 0)
            {
                echo 'Data Inserted';
                }else{
                    echo'Data not Inserted';
                }   

            }
        } catch(Exception $ex) {
            echo 'Error Insert'.$ex->getMessmessage();
        }
}
?>  
    </div>
    <div class = "footer py-5 bg-secondary">
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **WARNING:** When using `mysqli_` functions, you should ALWAYS use [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and the function [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to protect against SQL-Injections. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because it creates a severe SQL injection bug. **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data in a query directly. This can be very harmful if someones seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Have you enabled any debugging options or even just logged values to make sure what you think is happening is really happening?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in 'input value' properties. You set it to empty variables. Remove value from input tag like this:

```
<p class="text-center">Vardas</p><br><input type="text" name="Vardas" placeholder="Vardas">
```

it should work. About your MySQL queries, they are vulnerable for SQL Injections attack. Use PDO to protect against SQL Injections.

Comment: Won't it work if the variables are below the text?There's no actual problem with the PHP to Mysql link?

Comment: Just remove value from input tags and it will work. The data will be load to database. I already check it by my self. If my answer help you, you can accept it like correct one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have already inserted values and if you want to use values="". Then, in your SQL, you should UPDATE and not INSERT. Also,as  rpm192 stated above you should use parameterized queries, otherwise you will face SQL injections. Good Luck!